# Stream Analytics: performing a JOIN on events and ref. data in JSON

Tags: json, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I'd like to perform a JOIN query on incoming JSON events and JSON reference data in Azure Stream Analytics.

The JSON events look like the following:

```
{"devicename":"12345","value":25}
```

The JSON Reference data (simplified) looks like the following:

```
{
"Id": "configuration",
"Sites": [{
    "Id": "b83939b5-6502-4140-b807-205162ac4939",
    "Name": "site1",
    "Location": {
        "Latitude": 5.000,
        "Longitude": 5.000
    },
    "Lines": [{
        "Id": "e707a451-948a-498e-80de-d61bc448a5ef",
        "Name": "line1",
        "Sections": [{
            "Id": "d17d762c-4291-4912-9dcf-72113c9f0b4b",
            "Name": "section1",
            "Sensors": [{
                "Id": "S1_PL1_LS1_M1_device_001",
                "Name": "sensor1",
                "ExpectedAVG": 55,
                "ExpectedMIN": 35,
                "ExpectedMAX": 75,
                "TypeOfSensor": "Humidity"
            }, {
                "Id": "S1_PL1_LS1_M1_device_002",
                "Name": "sensor2",
                "ExpectedAVG": 105,
                "ExpectedMIN": 90,
                "ExpectedMAX": 118,
                "TypeOfSensor": "Temperature"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

Now I'd like to perform a JOIN on the incoming device data and the reference data.

```
SELECT
    i.devicename as pk,
    i.value as rk,
    system.timestamp as time,
    r.Sites.Lines.Sections.Sensors.Temperature as Temperature,
    r.Sites.Lines.Sections.Sensors.Humidity as Humidity
INTO
    output
FROM 
    IoTHubStream i
INNER JOIN 
    Reference r ON r.Sites.Lines.Sections.Sensors.Id = i.devicename
```

Now how can this be done? The problem is that the reference data can change and I would like to handle this dynamically.
I'm thinking about using a WHERE statement but I don't know how this could look like, some advice/help is really welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the array elements using GetArrayElements described in this page  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt298451.aspx

If your data changes make it impossible to use GetArrayElements, please share details about how it changes.